# Intellisense is not working in Visual Studio Code - mssql extension

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code with the `mssql` extension.

I am expecting intellisense to help me with table names and column names.

But if I type

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.
```

and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> then I am hoping to see a list of tables. But I don't see anything. I believe my expectation that this should work is correct.  Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Seems to have gone away.   I pressed Ctrl-Shift-P and then 'MS SQL: Connect' and it is working now.  Yesterday, I had written a .SQL file, and then allowed it to prompt me to connect.   If I can reproduce the problem consistently I might submit an issue and note it here.

Comment: My experience is that context matters when starting new queries in VS Code. If I start a new query by context click from the database node I want, intellisense works for the schema. If I specify a connection to that database as James B mentioned, intellisense works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking now that this was because I hadn't established a database connection.  So I was getting Intellisense on keywords but not database tables or columns.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that's worth noting for anyone else that comes across this issue is that if you don't specify a database name when connecting(because you have multiple DBs under a single connection) - you will connect to 'master' and won't get any IntelliSense on the schema. I suspect this is because different Databases could have different Schemas.

If this is your situation and all your Schemas are the same I would suggest creating two connections; one with a DB name specified and one without. You could then get the IntelliSense on your named DB editor window and Copy and paste your code into your editor window with the 'master' connection obviously adding the "[use...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/use-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)" at the top of the window.

Hopefully a nicer solution to this issue is created but in the meantime this is what gets me by.